# Exoplayer Mime type for (.smi) subtitle files

Tags: android, exoplayer, subtitle

I am trying to integrate subtitles into videos using Exoplayer. Currently only `.srt` subtitle files are working with `MIMETypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP`. How do I make it work for `.smi` subtitle files.

```
MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration subtitleConfiguration = new MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration.Builder(Uri.parse(subTitlePath))
                .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP)//mime type
              .setSelectionFlags(C.SELECTION_FLAG_DEFAULT)
              .build();
        MediaItem mediaItem=new MediaItem.Builder()
              .setUri(Uri.parse(videoUri))
              .setSubtitleConfigurations(ImmutableList.of(subtitleConfiguration))
              .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to below thread (issue in github),

Ref : https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5869

The answer is that it is not possible to play that with the ExoPlayer at the moment, because we don't have a decoder for SAMI subtitles.

But in the future may we have the decoder and more support from ExoPlayer.